# Animation is not switching

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a lot of animations in my 2d game on unity. All of them work well becouse I uncheck "Has exit time" and make "Transit duration" to 0 between them. But I have problem with attack animation. It is not loop. If I make "Transit duration" to 0, then it is not ending only if I click something. So I make "Transit duration" to 0.3, but now it is not working immediatly on click as I need.

````
    Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    float speed = 6f;
    public int jump;
    private bool IsGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;


    private void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        IsGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.5f, whatIsGround); //Is player on ground
        if (IsGrounded && rb.velocity.y > -0.01f && rb.velocity.y < 0.01f) {
            jump = 0;
            if (anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Attack_1") == false) {
                anim.SetInteger("State", 0);
            }
        }
        if (jump == 3) {
            jump = 1;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) { //Running left
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
            if (IsGrounded && rb.velocity.y > -0.01f && rb.velocity.y < 0.01f) {
                anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) { //Running right
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
            if (IsGrounded && rb.velocity.y > -0.01f && rb.velocity.y < 0.01f) {
                anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
            }
        }
        if (rb.velocity.y > 0.01f) { //Animation of falling
            anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -0.01f) { //Animation of jumping
            anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (IsGrounded || jump < 2)) {
            jump += 1;
            if (jump == 1 || jump == 3) {
                anim.SetInteger("State", 5); //Another jumping animation
            }
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * 12f;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) { //Attack animation
            anim.SetInteger("State", 4);
        }
}
```[![My animator][1]][1]


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/GegLW.png
````

How I can make it work immediatly?

Answer (score 0):

Unchecking the box "Has Exit Time" allows your animations to interrupt eachother.

If your attack animation needs to finish before it can transition to another animation, you should check the box "Has Exit Time" to true. You can leave your transition duration set to 0.

Comment: It is the same with "Has exit time" checked. Attack animation is not switching

Answer (score 0):

I think I solved my problem: I just used Trigger to enter attack, not "State" int.

My code now:

```
Rigidbody2D rb;
    Animator anim;
    float speed = 6f;
    public int jump;
    private bool IsGrounded;
    public Transform groundCheck;
    public LayerMask whatIsGround;


    private void Start() {
        rb = GetComponent<Rigidbody2D>();
        anim = GetComponent<Animator>();
    }

    private void Update() {
        IsGrounded = Physics2D.OverlapCircle(groundCheck.position, 0.5f, whatIsGround); //
        if (IsGrounded && rb.velocity.y > -0.01f && rb.velocity.y < 0.01f) {
            jump = 0;
            anim.SetInteger("State", 0);
        }
        if (jump == 3) {
            jump = 1;
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") < 0) {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = true;
            if (IsGrounded && rb.velocity.y > -0.01f && rb.velocity.y < 0.01f && anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Attack_1") == false) {
                anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
            }
        }
        if (Input.GetAxis("Horizontal") > 0) {
            GetComponent<SpriteRenderer>().flipX = false;
            if (IsGrounded && rb.velocity.y > -0.01f && rb.velocity.y < 0.01f && anim.GetCurrentAnimatorStateInfo(0).IsName("Attack_1") == false) {
                anim.SetInteger("State", 1);
            }
        }
        if (rb.velocity.y > 0.01f) {
            anim.SetInteger("State", 2);
        }
        else if (rb.velocity.y < -0.01f) {
            anim.SetInteger("State", 3);
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.UpArrow) && (IsGrounded || jump < 2)) {
            jump += 1;
            if (jump == 1 || jump == 3) {
                anim.SetInteger("State", 5);
            }
            rb.velocity = Vector2.up * 12f;
        }
        if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Z)) {
            anim.SetTrigger("Attack");
        }
}
```